# Tag publicity,promotion,promotions can be merged into just publicity

Tags: discussion, recommendations, tag-synonyms

As the topic Says. I am posting this as apparently i do not have votes on either of the tags to suggest synonyms.

Comment: `publicity` questions have been retagged into `promotion`.

Comment: promotion could mean a promotion on the job. But there is no mistaking publicity

Comment: @Aditya Come to think of it, aren't promotion (in this context) and publicity just marketing?

Comment: Both promotion and publicity are the subset of marketing.I figured people might mistake promotion for a promotion on the job,That's why i suggested publicity

Comment: I figured marketing was a broader area which dealt with a lot more than promotions/publicity involving strategic  planing.

Comment: But what ever clears the confusion and limits the tags to one. Does the job just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is a good idea, there are only six questions matching all tags. Perhaps it would be better to simply retag them?

Comment: Yes i have asked the same. Are you referring to the questions? or some one re tagging all of them to publicity?

Comment: @aditya I think Josh meant "retag" so I edited to that..

Comment: I think "promotion" is the more natural choice of those three to be the master tag.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, I did mean retag. I also agree with @Anna, `[promotion]` seems most fitting.